# How to flatMap List in Dart?

Tags: dart

I can map list in Dart:

```
[1,2,3].map((e) => e + 1)
```

but how can I flatMap this list?
Code presented below does not work.

```
[1,2,3].flatMap((e) => [e, e+1])
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`expand` method is equivalent to flatMap in Dart.

```
[1,2,3].expand((e) => [e, e+1])
```

What is more interesting, the returned `Iterable` is lazy, and calls fuction for each element every time it's iterated.

Answer (score 16):

*Coming from Swift, [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap) seems to have a little different meaning than the OP needed. This is a supplemental answer.*

Given the following two dimensional list:

```dart
final list = [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]];
```

You can convert it into a single dimensional iterable like so:

```dart
final flattened = list.expand((element) => element);
// (1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4)
```

Or to a list by appending `toList`:

```dart
final flattened = list.expand((element) => element).toList();
// [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```